# Reason for removing event listener on disconnectedCallback of web component

Tags: web-component

I saw online a example of removing event listeners of a button in a web components dom in its `disconnectedCallback`:

```js
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = "<button>Click</button>";
    }

    myEvent() {
        ...
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", this.myEvent.bind(this));
    }

    // Removes event here:
    disconnectedCallback() {
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button").removeEventListener("click", this.myEvent.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Is there a reason for doing this? As the button is out of dom there wouldn't be issues with it firing? Is there memory leak concerns? It is not listed in the [events section of web components best practises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices#events). I could understand if was event listener on the window etc but don't understand the effects if the event is triggered by something which is not connected

Comment: You are correct, modern browsers remove listeners. The ``bind`` is kinda oldskool also. Use one ``attachListener(name,func,scope=this)`` method that stores ``scope.removeEventListener(name,func)`` **functions** in an array. Then do a ``forEach```in the disconnect

Comment: You are not disconnecting your click event. This is a common anti-pattern memory leak. ``this.myEvent.bind(this) !== this.myEvent.bind(this)`` in the same way ``{test:1} !== {test:1}``. Instead you need to assign the binding to a reference. Try ``this.myeventbound = this.myEvent.bind(this)`` and then ``.addEventListener("click", this.myeventbound)`` and ``.removeListener("click", this.myeventbound)``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reconnect an element any time and by doing that, you will attach twice an event;

```
const elem = document.createElement('my-component');

document.body.appendChild(elem);

document.body.removeChild(elem);
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

if your event is doing an API call, this will result in a duplicated request